# Errors using Awesome-CV template; Not sure why .cls isn't working

Tags: templates, document-classes, awesome-cv

I keep getting errors when typesetting the awesome-cv template regarding things I don't recall changing at all. I assumed it was a package error thing although I just recently downloaded the latest MiKTeX distribution, yet I still proceeded to use the MiKTeX console to make updates, but that didn't solve the problem at all. I also thought it had to do with a missing .cls file or that it wasn't included, but it's already present in the same folder and \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} is also in the main resume_cv.tex file, and I even downloaded the entire project from github(https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) but that also solved nothing. I don't understand why it's still not registering the .cls file at all. And so I'm stuck with the following error messages if I compile the resume_cv.tex and education.tex files.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Awesome Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (30/3/2020)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Claud D. Park (posquit0.bj@gmail.com) with modifications by 
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template must be compiled with XeLaTeX, the below lines will ensure this
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

% Colors for text - uncomment and modify
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{blah}{blah}
%\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 404-180, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{blah blah}

\email{blahblah}
%\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{Zukotsu88}
%\linkedin{posquit0}
%\skype{skypeid}
%\stackoverflow{SOid}{SOname}
%\twitter{@twit}
%\linkedin{linkedin name}
%\reddit{reddit account}
%\xing{xing name}
%\extrainfo{test} % Other text you want to include on this line

%\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert} % Your expertise/fields
%\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."} % A quote or statement

%\makecvfooter{\today}{Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}{\thepage} % Specify the letter footer with 3 arguments: (<left>, <center>, <right>), leave any of these blank if they are not needed

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{cv-sections/education.tex}
\input{cv-sections/skills.tex}
\input{cv-sections/experience.tex}
\input{cv-sections/extracurricular.tex}
\newpage % Force a new page for looks
%\input{cv-sections/honors.tex}
%\input{cv-sections/presentation.tex}
%\input{cv-sections/writing.tex}
%\input{cv-sections/committees.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



\cvsection{Education}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry
{B.S. in Computer Science} % Degree
{The University} % Institution
{something, TX} % Location
{Expected Graduation: May 2024} % Date(s)
% Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item{Relevant Coursework: Introduction to Java Programming, Spring (2021): Data Structures, Discrete Math}
\end{cvitems}
\cventry 
{Some High School}
{Austin}
{May 2020}
{GPA}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{cventries}
```

resume_cv.log errors The whole thing is here: [resume_cv.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1viZCDSLv8m42-kJLa4Te1NuK7kauT1Ra/view?usp=sharing)

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.7) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.9.16)  16 SEP 2020 18:43
entering extended mode
**./resume_cv.tex
(resume_cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-03> (awesome-cv.cls
Document Class: awesome-cv 2017/02/05 v1.6.1 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\c@figure=\count170
\c@table=\count171
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen135
\ar@mcellbox=\box45
\extrarowheight=\dimen136
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
\ar@cellbox=\box46
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.s
ty
Package: enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
\enitkv@toks@=\toks16
\labelindent=\skip51
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen137
\enit@toks=\toks17
\enit@inbox=\box47
\enit@count@id=\count172
\enitdp@description=\count173
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ragged2e\ragged2e.s
ty
Package: ragged2e 2019/07/28 v2.2 ragged2e Package (MS)
 (C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ms\everysel.sty
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip52
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip53
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip54
\CenteringRightskip=\skip55
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip56
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip57
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip58
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip59
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip60
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip61
\CenteringParindent=\skip62
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip63
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip64
\JustifyingParindent=\skip65
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.s
ty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count174
\Gm@cntv=\count175
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count176
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen138
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen139
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen143
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19

(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xetexconfig\geome
try.cfg))
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.s
ty
Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip66
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip67
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip68
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip69
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip70
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip71
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip72
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip73
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip74
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.
cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.
def
File: xetex.def 2020/08/26 v5.0i Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xifthen\xifthen.sty
Package: xifthen 2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count177
\calc@Bcount=\count178
\calc@Adimen=\dimen146
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen147
\calc@Askip=\skip75
\calc@Bskip=\skip76
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count179
\calc@Cskip=\skip77
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifmtarg\ifmtarg.sty
Package: ifmtarg 2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
))
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.s
ty
Package: etoolbox 2020/08/24 v2.5j e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count180
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.s
ty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(C:\Users\akusu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.s
ty
```

Comment: If by main document you mean resume_cv.tex, I've been running XeLaTeX on it the entire time which was how I got these errors in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstand. So I ran Latex on just two different files in this case. Was I not supposed to do that? But that doesn't change the fact xelatex produces errors on the main document.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at

https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/examples/cv/education.tex

You have the syntax incorrect, the `\begin{cvitems}` block should be *in* the last argument to `\cventry`  the given  example is

```
 \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering} % Degree
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)} % Institution
    {Pohang, S.Korea} % Location
    {Mar. 2010 - Aug. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

You have no `{}` surrounding the entries so the final argument to `\cventry` in your file is just the `\begin` of `\begin{cvitems}` which leads to multiple errors.

You should only run xelatex on the main file, the other files such as `education.tex` are input in to that and can not be run as stand alone documents, which is why your log on education.tex shows all the commands undefined.

Comment: In the beginning, by `\begin{cventries}` do you actually mean `\begin{cvitems}`"? I don't see it in `\cventry` at all

Comment: Yeah this in mind it works, thank you so much!

Comment: @AmirAtreides typo fixed, sorry about that